# i am getting error while inseting data into my database table from html page

Tags: php, html, mysql

This is my php code , I am warning at the line of inserting the data please provide the answer

```
                if($_POST['submitted'] == 1){

                    $q = "INSERT INTO user(fullname,email,password,conform-password,mobileno) VALUES ('$_POST[form-full-name]','$_POST[form-email]','$_POST[form-password]','$_POST[form-conform-password]','$_POST[form-mobile-no]')";

                    $r= mysqli_query($dbc,$q); 

                    if($r){

                        echo '<p>you are REGISTERED SUCCESSFULLY !</p>';
                    }
                    else{

                        echo '<p>your REGISTRATION FAILED !</p>'.mysqli_error($dbc);
                        echo '<p>'.$q.'</p>';
                    }

                }
```

[image]

//"plz give me the solution for my problem"

> Blockquote

Comment: Which line is line 61?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 if($_POST['submitted'] == 1)
{

  $full_name =$_POST['form-full-name'];
  $form_email=$_POST['form-email'];
  $password = $_POST['form-password'];
  $conform_pass=$_POST['form-conform-password'];
  $mobile =$_POST['form-mobile-no'];

  $q = "INSERT INTO user(fullname,email,password,conform-password,mobileno) VALUES ('$full_name','$form_email','$password','$conform_pass','$mobile')";

  $r= mysqli_query($dbc,$q); 

  if($r)
  {

   echo '<p>you are REGISTERED SUCCESSFULLY !</p>';
  }
  else{

    echo '<p>your REGISTRATION FAILED !</p>'.mysqli_error($dbc);
    echo '<p>'.$q.'</p>';
      }

    }
```

you missing the single quote  `$_POST['']` method

Answer (score 0):

```
Just try saving your posted form data to php variable and then use that in   your insert query.

For ex: 

$fullname = $_POST['form-full-name'];
$email = $_POST['form-email'];
$password = $_POST['form-password'];
$confirmpassword = $_POST['form-conform-password'];
$mobilenumber = $_POST['form-mobile-no'];

And then the query as 


$q = "INSERT INTO user(fullname,email,password,conform-password,mobileno) VALUES ('$fullname','$email ','$password ','$confirmpassword ','$mobilenumber ')";


Hope this help.
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if you don't want to assign variables so that no memory allocation occurs then you can try using this:

```
           <?php

            if($_POST['submitted'] == 1){

                  $q = "INSERT INTO user(`fullname`,`email`,`password`,`conform-password`,`mobileno`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

                  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($q);

                    if ( false===$stmt ) {

                    die('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));
                    }

                  $rc = $stmt->bind_param("sssss",  $_POST['form-full-name'], $_POST['form-email'], $_POST['form-password'], $_POST['form-conform-password'],$_POST['form-mobile-no']);


                  if ( false===$rc ) {

                      die('bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
                    }

                  $rc = $stmt->execute();
                    if ( false===$rc ) {
                      die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
                    }

                   $stmt->close();


            }
```

According to this example you have to use mobile number datatype as string in table field.

**Do not need to save confirm password in table and you should use prepare statement for insertion. It will make your query secure for insertion in this case**

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for ur response
I solved that one I have made 2 mistakes 
1)used "-", I replaced with _ underscore (ex:form_email)
2) I have used isset() function 
After changing above 2 things I am getting data in my database